# React useEffect infinite loop fetching data from an api

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hi I'm trying to make a twitter clone app. I am using React on the client side and Express on the server side and PostgreSQL as my database. So here's the problem, I'm trying to use the `useEffect` like this:

```
const [tweets, setTweets] = useState([]);
  const getTweets = async () => {
    const res = await api.get("/posts", {
      headers: { token: localStorage.token },
    });
    setTweets(res.data);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getTweets();
  }, [tweets]);
```

I have no idea why it's looping infinite times, am I using it correctly though? I want the tweets to be updated every time I post a tweet. It's working fine but it's running infinite times. I just want it to re-render if a tweet got posted.

Here's my server code for getting all the posts:

```
async all(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    return this.postRepository.find({
      relations: ["user"],
      order: {
        createdAt: "DESC",
      },
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is every time you change the tweets it executes `useEffect` and changes the tweets and so long and so forth, so it's natural that it loops infinitely, the solution is to add a trigger that you set to true when a tweet gets posted, so the solution would be like this

```
const [tweets, setTweets] = useState([]);
const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(false);
  const getTweets = async () => {
    const res = await api.get("/posts", {
      headers: { token: localStorage.token },
    });
    setTweets(res.data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getTweets();
    setIsFetching(false);
  }, [isFetching]);
```

and set some logic to use `setIsFetching(true)` in order to execute the `useEffect`

PS: if you use an empty array in useEffect, it would execute only when the component is mounted (at the start)

Comment: Oh I understand now. Thanks for explaining! But is this the best practice if I'm trying to implement a newsfeed (tweets) with useEffect?

Comment: Yes, this is what you should use for any real time data fetching from the api for all kinds of lists including tweets!

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
    getTweets();
  }, [tweets]); // [tweets means that hook works every time 'tweets' state changes]
```

so your getTweets function set tweets => as tweets are changed hook works again => call getTweets => ... = infinite loop

if you want to download tweets, use empty array instead - hook will work once then

Comment: sorry i can't comprehend your explanation :( but i get it now though

Comment: I wrote the same thing as a guy above - you had wrong dependencies list within your hook.

Answer (score 0):

Pass empty array as a second arg for calling it once otherwise for changing it on every tweet change it will re-trigger, so whenever state will change only then it will be re-rendered like Tarukami explained. One thing you can do is check the length like mentioned below so not to compare the whole object but just the length

```
useEffect(() => {
    getTweets();
  }, [tweets.length]);
```

This might raise an error `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` lint error (that's a bypass you can use it).
But if you want more tighter check you can compare the ids on each re-render (create a hash/key/id from all element in the array and compare them on each render) like so `[tweet id here]) // Only re-subscribe if id changes`